# Retrieve list of measures from cube to variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis, mdx

I want to retrieve list of all measures from respected cube into variable.

I have tried following query in queryBuilder of SSIS, but it gives error regarding syntax. But same  query executed in Analysis services SSMS.

```
select Distinct [MEASUREGROUP_NAME] AS [MEASUREGROUP] 
from $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES  
where cube_name ='XYZ'
```

How to do it ?
Any correction required ?

Comment: "Error regarding syntax" is nowhere near as helpful as the actual error message.

Comment: But it executed in SSMS..

Comment: Can you post the *exact* error message?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL that Analysis Services understands for metadata queries is rather limited. I am quite sure `DISTINCT` is not part of this limited SQL subset. If you want to run this query, you can access the [`MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUPS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126178.aspx) system view instead of `MDSCHEMA_MEASURES`, which does not need the `DISTINCT`, as it already uniquely lists the measure groups.

Alternatively, you could keep using the `MDSCHEMA_MEASURES` system view, remove the `DISTINCT` from your query, and then aggregate the result in SSIS using the SSIS "Aggregate" component. But this would be less efficient.

Comment: @Frankpi Error running mdx query :  does not have permission to access the referenced mining model, MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUPS, or the object does not exist

Comment: @Niks Are you sure you have no typo? Did you test `select * from $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUPS`?